# Listview XAML in Xamarin.Forms with button

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following image below which I have tried to design in XAML- Xamarin forms.

[image]

The xaml code is as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" HasUnevenRows="true" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Frame Padding="0,0,0,8" BackgroundColor="#edeeef" BorderColor="#edeeef">
                                        <Frame.Content>
                                            <Frame OutlineColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="White">
                                                <Frame.Content>

                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                                                               TextColor="Black"
                                                               FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
                                                               FontSize="16"
                                                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                                                            <Label Text="Engine coolant temperature sesnor 1 circuit intermittent (DTC Confirmed)" FontSize="11" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>

                                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                <Button Text="OBD" />
                                                                <Button Text="CUS" />
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </StackLayout>

                                                        <BoxView  
                                                            VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                                            WidthRequest="1"
                                                            HeightRequest="5"
                                                            Color="Blue"
                                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                                            Grid.Column="1"/>


                                                        <ffsvg:SvgCachedImage
                                                            Aspect="AspectFit"                                                     
                                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                            Source="Bin.png"
                                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                                            />

                                                    </Grid>

                                                </Frame.Content>
                                            </Frame>

                                        </Frame.Content>
                                    </Frame>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

The issue that I am having is that I am unable to draw the vertical right line separating the content and the square red box on the right.

When I am adding the image, it is adding extra padding on the bottom.

Can someone please help me to align the components properly as in the image above in XamarinForms? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of how it actually looks?

Comment: It looks pretty same.. just the vertical line does not meet both ends of the frame.

Comment: Could you try to remove the `HeightRequest` from the `BoxView`?

Comment: I have removed. Same effects. The vertical line just does not meet both ends :(

Comment: @jones try to delete padding in your `Frame`.

Comment: @ДенисЧорный This is what I just thought.

Comment: I have deleted. Nothing happens :(

Comment: @jones Seems to be very strange. You need to change some Horizontal/Vertical options for views and see what will happen.
For example, try to change for your `BoxView`: `VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand`, `HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand`. There might be a problem with filling the content, if you don't use Expand features...
I had the same problem, but with stack layout.

Comment: Nope. Nothing is working.

Comment: Does this behavior occur on all platforms?

Comment: remove both padding for frame and HeightRequest for box view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is quite messed up and should be cleaned up

- Within the `ViewCell`, you have two nested `Frames`, which causes the main issue: There is a padding on the inner `Frame` that and on the outer one, which prevent the separator to take the full height
- A nested `Grid` and `StackLayout` is most likely not necessary and definitely detrimental for your performance

Suggestions:

- Remove the outer `Frame` and add a `Margin` to the inner one
- Set the `Padding` of the inner frame to `0`
- Remove the `StackLayout` wrapped in the `Grid` and add the controls to the `Grid`

  - Add the `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` for controls that take more height/width in the `Grid`

Your XAML within the `ViewCell` will look like this:

```
<Frame Padding="0"
       Margin="5"
       BorderColor="Transparent"
       BackgroundColor="White"
       CornerRadius="10">
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="5" Padding="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="ItemName"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontFamily="OpenSans-Light"
               FontSize="16"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="End"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Margin="10,10,10,0" />

        <Label Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Text="Engine coolant temperature sesnor 1 circuit intermittent (DTC Confirmed)"
               FontSize="11"
               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
               Margin="10,0,0,0" />


        <Button Text="OBD"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="10,0,5,10" />
        <Button Text="CUS"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="0,0,10,10" />


        <BoxView VerticalOptions="Fill"
                 HorizontalOptions="End"
                 WidthRequest="1"
                 Color="LightPink"
                 Margin="0"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.RowSpan="3" />


        <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="End"
               Source="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-200.jpg"
               Grid.Column="3"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.RowSpan="3"
               Margin="10"/>

    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

And eventually the design looks like that (There is still space for tweaking, but basically that's it. I've changed the colors a bit for better visibility):

[image: The updated design.]

Comment: I will add a screenshot in a minute

Comment: I'm glad I've been able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this Code.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Padding="{StaticResource Padding15050}">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewFood" ItemsSource="{Binding FoodList}" HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemSelected="OnSelection" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="{StaticResource Padding510}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Controls:Label x:Name="LabelName" Grid.Row="0" Text = "{Binding Name}"  Font="17" TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"/>
                                <Controls:Label x:Name="LabelDescription" Grid.Row="1" Text = "{Binding Description}" Font="15" />
                                <Controls:Label x:Name="LabelPrice" Grid.Row="2" Text = "{Binding Price}" Font="15" TextColor="{StaticResource YetiBlue}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Controls:RectangleButton Text="Add" Font="Bold,15"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"  Clicked="RectangleButton_Clicked"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**Design** like this.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of how this looks like ?

Comment: Check now @jones

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a separate line, you just need to add a `BoxView` in your xaml with `WidthRequest=1`.
I always use this solution for separating content.
In your case I would suggest to delete `HeightRequest` in your `BoxView`.

Comment: Did you read the OPs question and XAML? This is what xe did, but there seems to be an extra padding xe can't overcome.